# Return a ModelAndView with a List Object Simultaneously

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a List of `Managers` that I need to return in my `@Controller` method. I also have a User form view that I need to return simultaneously. `managerList` is returned from a previous `@Controller`. I may have been staring at this screen to long, it may not even make sense to do so, but can this be done?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getuserForm", produces = "text/html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView returnUserForm(
            @ModelAttribute("managerList") List<Manager> managerList,
            Model model) {
        //how to include managerList
        return new ModelAndView("userForm");
    }
```

Output would be a blank user form with a List of managers that say would be loaded into a select input. Any ideas?
Thanks much

Answer (score 1):

You can use use `public ModelAndView(String viewName, Map<String, ?> model)`.In model you can put your list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the model map of the ModelAndView Object

try the below code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getuserForm", produces = "text/html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView returnUserForm(
        @ModelAttribute("managerList") List<Manager> managerList,
        Model model) {
    //how to include managerList
    ModelAndView mnv=  new ModelAndView("userForm");
    mnv.getModelMap().addAttribute("managerList", managerList);
    return mnv;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getuserForm", produces = "text/html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView returnUserForm(
        @ModelAttribute("managerList") List<Manager> managerList,
        Model model) {
    //how to include managerList
    model.addObject("managerList", managerList);
    ModelAndView mnv=  new ModelAndView("userForm");
    mnv.getModelMap().addAttribute("managerList", managerList);
    return mnv;
}
```